# prettyPhoto stuck on load in modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, prettyphoto

I am working on a site with a gallery page ([www.eastcoastglassnc.com/projects.hmtl](http://www.eastcoastglassnc.com/projects.html)). The issues that I am running into is the modal window appears as it should, but it gets stuck on the loading wheel. I know the issue is something that I am probably overlooking so I figured I would get a fresh set of eyes. Here is the code I am working with.

Thumbnail HTML:

```
<div class="box col5"><a href="style/images/projects/bbt/bbt1.jpg" data-gal="prettyPhoto" title=""><span class="overlay zoom"></span><img src="style/images/projects/bbt/thumb1.png" alt=""/></a></div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("a[data-gal^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({autoplay_slideshow: false, overlay_gallery: false, social_tools:false, deeplinking: false, theme:'pp_default', slideshow:5000, hook: 'data-gal'});
    });
```

jQuery

```
// Find out if the picture is part of a set
        theRel = $(this).attr('data-gal');
        galleryRegExp = /\[(?:.*)\]/;
        isSet = (galleryRegExp.exec(theRel)) ? true : false;

        // Put the SRCs, TITLEs, ALTs into an array.
        pp_images = (isSet) ? jQuery.map(matchedObjects, function(n, i){ if($(n).attr('data-gal').indexOf(theRel) != -1) return $(n).attr('href'); }) : $.makeArray($(this).attr('href'));
        pp_titles = (isSet) ? jQuery.map(matchedObjects, function(n, i){ if($(n).attr('data-gal').indexOf(theRel) != -1) return ($(n).find('img').attr('alt')) ? $(n).find('img').attr('alt') : ""; }) : $.makeArray($(this).find('img').attr('alt'));
        pp_descriptions = (isSet) ? jQuery.map(matchedObjects, function(n, i){ if($(n).attr('data-gal').indexOf(theRel) != -1) return ($(n).attr('title')) ? $(n).attr('title') : ""; }) : $.makeArray($(this).attr('title'));
```

Any input you have would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you be able to install the "Firebug" plugin for firefox, and run this again?

(If you could put the output from Firebug's "console" into the ticket that would really help!)

I tried visiting that page, but the modal is gone, and clicking the image simply results in the image, not prettyPhoto. :(

Comment: The Firebug error is "too much recursion" and throws up the code for the jquery-1.6.2.min.js file. Line 16.

Exact Error Message:
too much recursion
http://eastcoastglassnc.com/style/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js
Line 16